# Spray testing basicauth from js html

Tags: scala, spray

I have code like: 
https://gist.github.com/daaatz/7665224

but dont know how to test request. 
Trying mydomain/secured?user=John&password=p4ssw0rd etc but nothing works.

Can some one tell me or show example in js+html how to check is it working fine ?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to AlexIv's excellent answer you should read up on how HTTP basic authentication works. It doesn't use query parameters but HTTP headers for authentication. Maybe that's what you are missing. To try it in a browser use this syntax: `http://user@mydomain/secured`. The browser should then prompt you with a dialog to enter the password.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used BasicAuth in Spray, so i'm not sure if this would be the complete answer, but i hope this will help you.

At first. in spray there is a great [spray-testkit](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-RC4/spray-testkit/) written on top of akka testkit. You should definitely check out `SecurityDirectives` test on [github](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing-tests/src/test/scala/spray/routing/SecurityDirectivesSpec.scala), this will show you how to test basic authentication. A little example, to make this simpler:

As for your route example, i would better edit to the following one:

```
val myRoute =
  (path("secured") & get) {
     authenticate(BasicAuth(myUserPassAuthenticator _, realm = "secure site")) {                      
       userName => complete(s"The user is '$userName'")
     }
  }
}
```

Adding `get` directive will specify that this route expects a `Get` request and `sealRoute` is obsolete cause `RejectionHandler` and `ExceptionHandler` are provided implicitly with `runRoute`. It is used only in tests, if you want wo check exceptions/rejections.

Now in your tests you should construct auth entities, similar to the test one:

```
val challenge = `WWW-Authenticate`(HttpChallenge("Basic", "Realm"))

val doAuth = BasicAuth(UserPassAuthenticator[BasicUserContext] { userPassOption ⇒
  Future.successful(Some(BasicUserContext(userPassOption.get.user)))
}, "Realm")
```

And you test case:

```
"simple auth test" in {
   Get("security") ~> Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials("Alice", "")) ~> {
     authenticate(doAuth) { echoComplete }
   } ~> check { responseAs[String] === "BasicUserContext(Alice)" }
}
```

In `Get("security")` specifies that your test will send a `Get` request on "/security", then add `Authorization` to the test request, some action and the `check` part to test the request.

I've never tried to test BasicAuth, so there could be some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into CURL for testing routes in web applications, but I've also used the chrome extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) with great results as well.